# OpenSSL EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding not working

Tags: openssl, aes, padding

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt using AES, CBC and PKCS#7 padding using the EVP interface. I am using the [example found on the Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption).

I am doing `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0)` after creating and initializing the context which should not add padding and fail if the plaintext is not a multiple of 16 bytes. Despite this the ciphertext always contains an extra block made up of padding only.

The code I am using is literally copied and pasted from the tutorial, I am only adding `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0)` in both encrypt and decrypt like so:

```
/* Create and initialise the context */
if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've formatted your question for you, you can take a look at the edits by clicking on [edited <time> ago](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41474613/revisions). Backticks are useful for inline code, don't over-use the quoting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently both `EVP_DecryptInit_ex` and `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` re-initialize the context so any context changes (such as setting the padding) should be performed after those methods have been called.

Comment: Actually, looking at the manpages, it does say that, but it doesn't explicitly say anything about the padding mode etc. So this makes up a pretty nice Q/A. Thanks for reporting back.

Comment: Spent a hour debugging the very same behaviour till I found your answer.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Spent half a day fighting this... Thank you.